# Where can I find HAM forum, newsgroup, etc?

Tags: diy

Where can I find HAM forum, newsgroup, discussion, chat room, etc., either formal or light hearted, apart from this one?

Comment: Try a [search engine](http://google.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

QRZ.com has forums, news postings, classifieds and similar to what you are looking for.

radioreference.com has forums, news, and similar with lots of Amateur discussion, but is not strictly Amateur specific. You can learn a lot from this site.

There are many more to be found on the Google and you are likely to find some that are more appealing to you than others.

Answer (score 2):

International newsgroups: rec.radio.amateur.* and there are regional newsgroups related to amateur radio.
Google+ also has some amateur radio related 'communities'.